# The help-center contains links to meta.codereview.* instead to codereview.meta.*

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for example:

> For more information on this policy, please see [this post on our Meta site](https://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763).

A user gets greeted with an "unsecure connection" warning, since the certificate isn't valid for `meta.codereview.stackexchange.com`, but for `codereview.meta.stackexchange.com`.

Further help-pages with the old links:

- <del>https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask (last paragraph)</del>
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers ("code only answers")
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer (1st and 3rd link)

Comment: Just ran into one here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask "may be on-topic for Stack Overflow" ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed the links on:

- [/help/someone-answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)
- [/help/how-to-answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for reporting this. I fixed it on:

- [/help/on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [/help/dont-ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

I could not fix it on [/help/someone-answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), that's not editable by local mods. I'll ask on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) to make it editable, so we can fix it.

I will update this post when all are done.

Comment: @Zeta for the links on /someone-answers and /how-to-answer, although I see they are wrong as I hover, when I click they get redirected to the correct page. Do you get an error? (I'm a bit puzzled why some links are redirected while others not... I will investigate more later tonight.)

Comment: Oooohhhh... Those are HTTP links. Therefore, you don't get the certificate warning and the redirect works fine.

Comment: long story short: this was missed during the https-migration? Might be useful to prod @NickCraver about it. IIUC he was primarily responsible for post rewrites

Comment: [Nick Craver prodded and reply received](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/889917135207755776)