# Insecure Connection error in help page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

In the [help center](/help) page, there is a description below the search box as:

> For more information, also see posts on Code Review meta tagged with [`[faq]`](https://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq?sort=votes).

When clicked on the `[faq]` link, it returns the **Insecure Connection error**.

Currently the `[faq]` link is linked with the URL

> `https://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq?sort=votes`

but this URL need to be change as

> `https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq?sort=votes`

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Faq error]

Comment: Related to [this list of other](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7359/21002) mismatches :).

Comment: [Nick Craver prodded and reply received](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/889917135207755776)

Comment: Fixed it, thanks for reporting.